# Is every element in weakly prime ideal a nilpotent element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In D. D. Anderson and Eric Smith, *Weakly prime ideals*, **2003**. $R$ is commutative ring with identity

There is a theorem:

"Let $P$ be a weakly prime ideal of $R$. If $P$ is not prime, then $P^2=0$"

And then there is a Corollary:

"Let $P$ be a weakly prime ideal of $R$. Then $P \subseteq \sqrt{0}$ or $\sqrt{0} \subseteq P$."

I've try to prove this, but I'm stuck.

We have $\sqrt{0}=\{r\in R \mid r^n\in 0, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \}$

by the corollary (i mean is to proof $P \subseteq \sqrt{0}$ ), my idea is we must proof that

"if we take whenever $x \in P$, then $x \in \sqrt{0}$. In other word, if we take $x \in P$, then $x$ is nilpotent element. (because must be there is $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, so that $x^n \in 0$ equivalent with $x^n=0$)"

i'm stuck here, how to show that every weakly prime ideal elements is nilpotent element?

I'm attaching the picture of the corollary, maybe you need it

[Theorem & Corollary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05yyx.png)

i hope, you can help me. Thank You very much

*I'm sorry if my english is so bad, but i will always try to be better*

Answer (score 1):

For other people's reference, an ideal $I$ is defined to be weakly prime if $0 \not= ab \in I$ implies $a \in I $ or $b \in I$.

The theorem implies that a weakly prime ideal $P$ is either prime or is such that $P^2 =0$. If $P^2 = 0$ then $p^2 = 0$ for each $p \in P$, so $P$ consists of nilpotents, i e. $P \subseteq \sqrt{0}$.  On the other hand, for any prime $P$ we have $\sqrt{0} \subseteq P$. You should check this for yourself. Consider the basic case that $r^2 =0$. Since $0 \in P$, the definition of a prime ideal implies that $r \in P$. Use induction to show that $r^n =0$ implies  $r \in P$.